# How do I get data from my database into my Custom Export Field

Tags: php, sql, xml, csv

I am trying to get data from my database to export to a XML or CSV File by using a custom query. This is my function with the query :

```
<?php
function get_workhours($ID){
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT worked_hours FROM db_info WHERE job_id = $ID");
    $data = $wpdb->query($sql);
    if(empty($data)){
        return "0";
    }else{
        return $data;
} ?>
```

And in my custom export field i have this :

```
[get_workhours{ID}]
```

And when I try to preview this it gives me the error :

> An unknown error occured.

Suggestions for a better idea for this problem are very welcome aswell.

Thanks in advance,

EDIT : I am using the WP All Export Pro Plugin. When adding a field to export I choose the option : Custom export field.

Comment: What is 'custom export field'?

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax is wrong.
It should be [get_workhours({ID})].
Also press "Save Functions" button before previewing.